# The imported target "Qt5::Gui" references the file "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so" but this file does not exist.

Tags: compiling, libraries, opengl

So, 15.04 x64, just installed.

I installed the nvidia binary in the old way (console, switching off lightdm) because I got an error about DRI2 authentication.

Then I wanted to build the nv opengl samples and they say these were the prerequisite:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ binutils-gold xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

But then it complained about libGL.so missing, so googling around I tried to install all these things:

```
   61  sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev 
   62  sudo apt-get autoremove
   63  make
   64  sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev 
   65  sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev freeglut3
   66  make
   67  sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and then, I dont know how, I ended up with the nvidia drivers unistalled! (There was also an autoremove in middle containing some nv stuff, maybe that messed up everything)

Anyway, after reinstalling again the nv binaries, I try to build vogl (a GL debug tool) and I get again

```
elect@elect-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/vogl/vogl_build/release64$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_X64=On ../..

cmake options:
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release': Build debug or release. (Debug|Release)
  -DVOGLTEST_LOAD_LIBVOGLTRACE='': glitest will load libvogltrace.so manually (don't implictly link against libgl.so). (On|Off)
  -DVOGLTRACE_NO_PUBLIC_EXPORTS='OFF': Don't define any public GL exports in libvogltrace.so. (On|Off)
  -DVOGL_ENABLE_ASSERTS='OFF': Enable assertions in all voglcore builds (including release). (On|Off)
  -DCMAKE_VERBOSE='OFF': Spew cmake project options. (On|Off)
  -DBUILD_X64='On': Build 32 or 64-bit. (On|Off)
  -DWITH_ASAN='OFF': Build with Address sanitizer. (On|Off)
  -DUSE_TELEMETRY='OFF': Build with Telemetry. (On|Off)
  -DUSE_MALLOC='': Use system malloc (not STB Malloc). (On|Off)

Not forcing assertions to be enabled (VOGL_ENABLE_ASSERTS=FALSE)
libvogltrace.so will define GL/GLX public exports
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:27 (message):
  The imported target "Qt5::Gui" references the file

     "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:32 (_qt5_Gui_check_file_exists)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:54 (_qt5gui_find_extra_libs)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:158 (include)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:100 (find_package)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:26 (find_package)
  src/vogleditor/CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/elect/NetBeansProjects/vogl/vogl_build/release64/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/elect/NetBeansProjects/vogl/vogl_build/release64/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

elect@elect-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/vogl/vogl_build/release64$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep -i libegl
libEGL.so
libEGL.so.1
libEGL.so.346.59
```

What's wrong, guys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anyway let me sum up the story..

```
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep -i libegl
libEGL.so 
libEGL.so.1 
libEGL.so.346.59

ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 mar 30 17:10 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so -> mesa-egl/libEGL.so
```

and

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 mar 30 17:10 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libEGL.so -> libEGL.so.1.0.0
```

But I didnt do have any libEGL.so.1.0.0..

So it looks like it was a mess coming from mesa and nv binaries

I installed the binaries a third time and it worked..

Another possible solution is the one of Angelo Geels (in the comments):

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so; sudo ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Well, it looks like mesa messed up the links of the gl libs, I can later post a  clarification of what was wrong

Comment: @NewUSer It *is* the answer.. Posted by the OP himself.

Comment: @NewUSer, updated

Comment: @elect that's much more better +1

Comment: @NewUSer thanks! Sorry for the first version but I was in a hurry and didnt have so much time but I still wanted to say I solved so that nobody would have wasted time on that or somebody with the same problem could have solved it.. :)

Comment: I can't add another answer because it is closed, but I solved this problem by re-doing the symlink: `sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so; sudo ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I can report it in the answer